# Unable to extract yahoo finance data

Tags: python, pandas, selenium-webdriver

```
`from selenium import webdriver
import pandas as pd
import re

# Read the Excel file with the links
df = pd.read_excel('file.xlsx')

# Create empty lists to store the extracted data
company_names = []
earnings_dates = []

# Set up the Selenium driver
driver = webdriver.Chrome()

# Iterate over the links in the DataFrame
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    url = row['Link']  # Assuming the links are in column 'Link'

    # Load the URL in the browser
    driver.get(url)

    # Extract the company name using regular expressions
    try:
        html_content = driver.page_source
        match = re.search(r'<h1 class="D\(ib\) Fz\(18px\)">(.*?)</h1>', html_content)
        if match:
            company_name = match.group(1)
        else:
            company_name = 'Company name not found'
    except:
        company_name = 'Company name not found'

    # Extract the earnings date
    try:
        earnings_date_element = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//td[contains(text(), "Earnings Date")]/following-sibling::td')
        earnings_date = earnings_date_element.text.strip()
    except:
        earnings_date = 'Earnings date not found'

    # Append the extracted data to the lists
    company_names.append(company_name)
    earnings_dates.append(earnings_date)

# Close the Selenium driver
driver.quit()

# Create a new DataFrame with the extracted data
df_extracted = pd.DataFrame({'Link': df['Link'], 'Company Name': company_names, 'Earnings Date': earnings_dates})

# Print the extracted data
print(df_extracted)`
```

Above code I'am able to extract company name but unable to extract Earning date--

https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/A?p=A&.tsrc=fin-srch
Trying to extract below result
**Agilent Technologies, Inc. (A)**
**Earnings Date Aug 14, 2023 - Aug 18, 2023**

Comment: Why don't you use their API?

Comment: Post an example of your csv file

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1MqJj3geJNYOWBKQ48wofZsjmZopC121j/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=112576821891522736032&rtpof=true&sd=true please find excel file

Comment: @CeliusStingher how can i use can you guide

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the [Yahoo Finance](https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/A?p=A&.tsrc=fin-srch) webpage the **Company Name** is within the only `<h1>` tag on the webpage:

[image: CompanyName]

---

### Solution

To extract the ***Company Name*** and the ***Earnings Date*** you can use the following [locator strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver):

```
driver.get("https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/A?p=A&.tsrc=fin-srch")
print(driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "h1").text)
print(driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//td[.//span[text()='Earnings Date']]//following-sibling::td[1]").text)
```

Console Output:

```
Agilent Technologies, Inc. (A)
Aug 14, 2023 - Aug 18, 2023
```

**Note** : You have to add the following imports :

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
```

Comment: Thank you #undetected Selenium above is working.